# How to override the default behaviour of the navigation drawer in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I there a way to let the navigation drawer close (go off the screen) more than the screen width?

The reason I am asking this is because in my navigation drawer, I have an icon floating outside the navigation drawer like this

[image]

And when the drawer is closed here is the result

[image]

As you can see the floating part is still visible.

Here is my code

```
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
      Home: { screen: Home },
      Anatomy: { screen: Anatomy },
      Header: { screen: Header },
      Footer: { screen: Footer },
      NHBadge: { screen: NHBadge }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Home",
      drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
      drawerPosition: 'right',
      drawerWidth: 300,
      contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
    }
    );
```

And this is the SideBar code

```
  render() {
return (
  <Container>
    <View style={styles.drawerCover} />
    <Image square style={styles.drawerImage} source={drawerImage} />

    <Content
      bounces={false}
      style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff", top: -1 }}
    >

      <List
        dataArray={datas}
        renderRow={data =>
          <ListItem
            button
            noBorder
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route)}
          >
            <Left>
              <Icon
                active
                name={data.icon}
                style={{ color: "#777", fontSize: 26, width: 30 }}
              />
              <Text style={styles.text}>
                {data.name}
              </Text>
            </Left>
            {data.types &&
              <Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Badge
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    height: 25,
                    width: 72,
                    backgroundColor: data.bg
                  }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={styles.badgeText}
                  >{`${data.types} Types`}</Text>
                </Badge>
              </Right>}
          </ListItem>}
      />
    </Content>
  </Container>
);
}
}
```

**EDIT : Solution**

This is how I solved the issue:
[Changed the render of the image depending on the state of the navigation drawer (close / open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60091697/how-to-make-component-re-rendering-in-react-native-faster/60096427#60096427)

Comment: You can try setting the opacity of the image on the drawer to 0 when the drawer closes, and to 1 when he opens.
With something like:

    
<Image square style={[styles.drawerImage, {opacity: (IsDrawerOpen ? 1 : 0)}]} source={drawerImage} />

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior Actually that's how I fixed the issue, take a look at the edited question. Thank you :) .